# How to execute cucumber-jvm features one after another

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am using Cucumber-JVM and Selenium to write Automated BDD tests. I have 2 feature files defined both having 2 scenarios each and have 2 step definition files written in java. This is a Maven project and when I build the project using **maven test**, it is executing both the features in parallel but I want them to execute one by one. Do we have some way to do that?

Below is the Runner file:

```
package Demo.Selenium.Cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber",
    "json:target_json/cucumber.json", "junit:taget_junit/cucumber.xml" }, tags = { "@Smoke" })
public class CukeTest {
}
```

Please lemme know if you need more info.

Comment: Could you post your pom file?. Probably the surefire plugin or similar is using forks

Comment: I have uploaded the pom file here : http://www.filedropper.com/pom_1. Please have a look.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in your pom. As far as i know, the concurrency is not set by default in Junit execution. Could you check you Before and BeforeClass annotations and verify that your not opening two browser at the same time?.